# Cleartext HTTP traffic is not permitted inspite of adding android:usesCleartextTraffic and android:networkSecurityConfig

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-volley

So as he title reads, volley is throwing the error of "Clear text http traffic not permitted" inspite of adding all the necessary changes in android manifest file as well network config security file. I'm making my project in android studio and would appreciate some help. I have tried cleaning the project, rebuilding it and invalidating caches too. Nothing works.

Manifest File:(can't show package name)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:dist="http://schemas.android.com/apk/distribution"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        tools:replace="android:networkSecurityConfig">
        <activity android:name=".SplashScreen"
                  android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".VerifyOtp" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        </activity>
    </application>

    <dist:module dist:instant="true" />

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

if your Url is "https://example.com" then just add example.com and other url that you want to allow access, like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">example.com</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">example1.com</domain>
    </domain-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="false" />
</network-security-config>
```

Comment: Tried this one too. No luck whatsoever.

Comment: **network config:**  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">http://127.0.0.1</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>

Comment: Just added both for you to check

Comment: Can you please remove this line and try .tools:replace="android:networkSecurityConfig"

Comment: I don't think I follow. I have added the line there to indicate the new security rules. Do you want me to remove it??